# Magento - 'submit shipping' btn is not working on admin page

Tags: javascript, php, magento

Once an order is confirmed, i also confirm the shipment about that order.

So on Sales > order, i click the ship btn located in upper right side. Then, i write down the tracking code and submit the shipment!

The the button of "submit shipping" is not working!

The problem is it does not display javascript error or php error, browser console stays clean, nothing happens on the screen. It's as if the button does nothing.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfbJQ.jpg)

Comment: turn off adblocker? check for javascript errors? post code? see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for help on `How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example`

Comment: The problem is it does not display javascript or php error, browser console stays clean, nothing happens on the screen. It's as if the button does nothing.

Comment: I checked the bug report on chrome,firefox even IE edge and log file as well, i can see nothing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved:
Change the file: items.phtml
app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\sales\order\shipment\create\items.phtml

Change the function **submitShipment** to:

```
function submitShipment(btn) {
 var checkbox = $(btn).up('.order-totals').select('#create_shipping_label')[0];

 if (!validQtyItems()) {
        return;
    }
    disableElements('submit-button');
    $('edit_form').submit();    
}
```